# Getting "Sessions still open, not unmounting" when exiting psql. What does this mean?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

When I quit `psql` after setting up a new role, `psql` now complains on exit;

> Sessions still open, not unmounting

Doing a quick google search didn't reveal anything of value in regards to this msg.  **What does it mean and should I do anything about it?**

**EDIT**

This is a setup on Ubuntu Server 12.04 32 with lvm encryption on file system.

Comment: I'm virtually certain this is not a Postgres error: that string appears nowhere in the Postgres source code. What operating system are you using? (Please update your question and tags to provide more detail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, based on what I've gleaned from Google, is that you have an ecryptfs encrypted filesystem which tries to unmount as part of your logout scripts.
[These filesystems won't unmount if a user is using them](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/507150), and as noted on that bug report this behavior is by design.

You can probably ignore this message (and you can certainly ignore it from a Postgres perspective), but if it really bothers you the folks on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) can probably offer more insight into why you're seeing it and how to make it go away...

Comment: Thx again voretaq7.  Was actually working the same angle once you pointed out the it didn't seem like a postgres issue.